# Will I get continued access to DRONE The Game if I purchase it during Early Access?

Tags: drone-the-game

I am curious about D.R.O.N.E. the game early access on steam.  What happens as the game is updated if I get the Early Access?  Will I get free access to all updates if I buy the Early Access, including the final edition of the game?  If not, will I have to pay the entire price all over again?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Arqade! I'm voting to close your question since it seems to lack some focus, and has multiple questions in one post. Check out the [Tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [Help Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) for some more detailed info on asking better questions!

Comment: Hi, Kaizerwolf!  I asked all questions together because I thought it would be ridiculous to create several different questions at once.

Comment: I think splitting them in two would be ok - one question about early access, and one about the gameplay

Comment: This question is definitely focused enough for it to remain open.  closing it seems completely ridiculous.

Comment: For the Early Access question, Steam says ["You keep access to the game, even if the game later moves from Early Access into fully released."](https://store.steampowered.com/earlyaccessfaq/?snr=1_5_9_)

Comment: Does that mean I get the updates to the game as they come out?

Comment: You own a copy of the game and will get all updates available to the version you own. If they release multiple versions and have some content only for the others and not your version then you won't get that unless it's available as a DLC **and** you buy it.